# How to get value of Date Picker from Material Ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

If I created a datepicker with Material Ui, how do I get the user's input value?

Say the user selects 01.01.2016-> how do i grab that value and store it as a variable with data type date?

So far what I've tried to do is use states to pass back a JSON object but that doesnt seem to be working. For example:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      startDate: null,
      endDate:null    
    };
  },

render: function() {
return (
      <div>
          <DatePicker hintText="Start Date" value={this.state.startDate}  onChange={this._handleStartInput} />
          <DatePicker hintText="End Date" value={this.state.endDate} onChange={this._handleEndInput} />
      </div>
);},

_handleStartInput: function(value) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: value
    });
  },

  _handleEndInput: function(value) {
    this.setState({
      endDate: value
    });
  },
```

And then from there I can create another function that pulls the value, but right now after I select a date, the state never changes and is displayed in the UI.

Comment: What does `value` looks like in `_handleStartInput` and `_handleEndInput`? I think that value is an event, so you can try `value.target.value`

Comment: @Road right now when I log them, they are null. I tried value.target.value and it still returns null

Comment: is your `DatePicker` component custom made or from a library which uses Material UI as the design? What does your `DatePicker` looks like?

Comment: No DatePicker is a component from the material UI library. Here is the documentation for it: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

Comment: try binding `this` eg `this._handleStartInput.bind(this)`. The docs are using an autobinding feature with class https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

Comment: @Road still returns null for both `startDate` and `endDate`

Comment: after binding `this`, it will expect two args `(event, date)`. So in your `_handleStartInput`. Try using `function(event, date)` instead of `function(value)`. then use `date` as the arg for `this.setState`

Comment: @Road that worked! I'm recieving these warnings however: `Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop onDismiss of type boolean supplied to Dialog, expected function. Check the render method of DatePickerDialog.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99870/discussion-between-road-and-ogk).

Answer (score 4):

I tried this and I paint the console value

```
<DatePicker  container="inline" floatingLabelText="Fecha desde" onChange={(x, event) => this.setFechaDesde(x,event)}    defaultDate={new Date()} />
```

and

```
setFechaDesde(x,event){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Material-UI are you using ?

By reading the doc you see that

> *onChange* Callback function that is fired when the date value changes. Since there is no particular event associated with the change the first argument will always be null and the second argument will be the new Date instance.

You should try adding a second param to your callbacks.

Comment: `<DatePicker name="startDate" autoOk={true} floatingLabelText="startDate" onChange={(x, event) => {console.log(arguments);}} />` on console always I can see empty array, "material-ui": "0.15.0"

Answer (score 1):

Your onChange handler functions should take two parameters: event and date, where event is always null and date is the new date object.

```
_handleStartInput: function(event, date) {
    var currentState = this.state;
    currentState.startDate = date;
    this.setState(currentState);
},

_handleEndInput: function(event, date) {
    var currentState = this.state;
    currentState.endDate = date;
    this.setState(currentState);
}
```